# Triple vector product and Triple scalar product for complex vectors

Tags: complex-analysis, vectors

Can we apply the same formula of the "vector triple product" *and* "vector scalar product" for complex vectors (that is, vectors with complex entries)?

Clearly, I assume we calculate the cross product with the complex vector formula, and that we also calculate the inner product with the complex vector formula (either antilinear to first argument, or antilinear to second argument).

Comment: What is meant by triple product here

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi most likely the formula $a\cdot(b\times c)$

Comment: What I mean with Triple vector product is: a x (b x c)